# Change Menu Text Color

Tags: android

How to change the text color of menu on action bar?
When I change the action bar color to white,the text color of menu is still white.So it is invisible. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this :

```
<style name="ThemeName" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light">
    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

I tried several things but nothing worked for me. Finally this did the trick:

```
<style name="your_theme" parent="your_parent">
    <item name="android:itemTextAppearance">@style/TextAppearance</item>
</style>

<style name="TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
</style>
```

I didn't use Sherlock themes. This worked for Holo.Light.DarkActionBar.

Comment: Sir, I mean that my app let user to change the action bar color,(black,red,blue,white).When users change to white, I want to change the menu text color on action bar to black.

Answer (score 0):

Action bar text color can be changed through "actionMenuTextColor"

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    ...
    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">#00000</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Sir, I mean that my app let user to change the action bar color,(black,red,blue,white).When users change to white, I want to change the menu text color on action bar to black.